# Animation over button only in CSS3

Tags: css

I'm trying to add an animation over the button. A faded png that goes from left to right. Problem now is that it goes full width of parent element and not only just over the button.

HTML:

```
<div style="background: yellow; height: 30px">    
    <button class="btn-primary btn" style="margin-left: 100px">
        Some button here
    </button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn:hover:not([disabled]):not(.disabled):before, a.btn:hover:not([disabled]):not(.disabled):before, .swipe-glow:hover:not([disabled]):not(.disabled):before {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0s ease, left 0.4s linear;
    transition: opacity 0s ease, left 0.4s linear;
    left: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}
.btn:before, a.btn:before, a.btn:before, .swipe-glow:before {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0, left 0s linear 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0, left 0s linear 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
    content:" ";
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('//eaassets-a.akamaihd.net/battlelog/bb/bfh/ui/swiping-glow-408c7792.png');
}
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/lasseedsvik/keanyvde/

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
.btn {position:relative; overflow:hidden;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/keanyvde/4/